# Why can't I access the utility methods in class members in T4 templates?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I'm trying to write a class in a T4 template that uses the [Text Template Utility Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126474.aspx) (like WriteLine, PushIndent, PopIndent). However, if I try to call these methods in my class, I'll get a compiler error stating

> Compiling transformation: Cannot access a non-static member of outer
>   type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation' via
>   nested type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBF13B4A5FBA992E5EF81A8A7A4EACCAC3F7698E169D0F7825ED4F22A28C7C52C2B766D83F4C5ACA13E0DE0B3152B6D966E34EB8C5FC677E145F55BE0485406EC.GeneratedTextTransformation.ClassGenerator'

A MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example) would look like this:

```cs
<#+
public void FunctionSample()
{
    WriteLine("Hello"); // This works fine
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public static void StaticMethodSample()
    {
        WriteLine("Hello"); // This does not compile
    }

    public void InstanceMethodSample()
    {
        WriteLine("Hello"); // This does not compile either
    }
}
#>
```

Is there any way to access these utility methods within a class scope or do I have to use free functions?

(I'm running on Visual Studio 2015 Community)

Comment: Utility methods like `WriteLine`, are **instance** methods of pattern class, so you need a reference to pattern instance to call them.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the info - could you also please tell me how I could get such an instance? I know the TextTransformation class - but it is abstract and has no Singleton pattern on it.

Comment: Instance of `TextTransformation` available as `this` in any instance method of template class, like `FunctionSample` in your example. That is why them can call utility methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) pointed out in the comments, you can just call the T4 Utility Methods in any "free function" in a Class Feature Control Block because they are inherited from the `TextTransformation` base class, i.e. these free functions are not exactly free, they are methods within the scope of an implicitly created class that derives from `TextTransformation`. That's why you can also access `this` in these functions.

So if you want to use a utility method in another class you defined in a T4 template (this class is actually a nested child class), you have to pass in a reference of TextTransformation to it, e.g. like this:

```cs
<#
var @object = new SampleClass(this); // Pass 'this' (TextTransformation) to the constructor
@object.SayHello();
#>

<#+
public class SampleClass // This is actually a nested child class in T4 templates
{
    private readonly TextTransformation _writer;

    public SampleClass(TextTransformation writer)
    {
        if (writer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        _writer.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
#>
```

More information can be found in the [MSDN library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126545.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: You'll probably also need to add `<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>` to your T4 to make this work.